# Social network for farmers and cooks with geographical map integration indicating land-specific seeding and harvesting times

Tags: web, maps, educational, social-networks, google-maps

I was wondering whether there are any apps on Android that allow one to view a map of the world and be able to click on any area and the app tells you what can grow on the land, when the stuff grows, how to grow the stuff (like when to water, and, with also a section with different growing techniques, stored by plant type and growing technique), with also a dictionary of different type of plants, and, according to where on the map you click, a list of what can grow along with when to plant and when to harvest is displayed.

As an application, I can use the map to figure out, for any given location or wider geographical area, when I can purchase which fresh "in season" crops at the supermarket.

Perhaps the app also has a section discussing the long term storage techniques for the food herbs or plant essences grown.

Ideally, there would be both an app and a website, where socializers (just like on any social network, but here farmers and preservers and cooks could come together) could post their techniques or discuss taste, or also which recipes to use the food in.

Thanks.